# use ISFORMULA with ARRAYFORMULA on a range of cells

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a row of cells, some with a formula, and some without.

I am trying to use `ARRAYFORMULA` WITH `IFFORMULA` to see if a cell has a formula or not. This is the function I am using:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ISFORMULA(B2:B))
```

But it just outputs one single value.

[image]

There are other things I need to do for each row/cell which is why I need `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Is there another way to get `ISFORMULA` to work with `ARRAYFORMULA`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not all functions are convertible into ArrayFormula. `ISFORMULA` is one of those...

the best you can do is pre-program it like:

```
={ISFORMULA(B2);
  ISFORMULA(B3);
  ISFORMULA(B4);
  ISFORMULA(B5);
  ISFORMULA(B6)}
```

[image: 0]

---

the next best thing you can do is to use conditional formatting to color it like:

green color:

```
=ISFORMULA($B2)
```

red color:

```
=NOT(ISFORMULA($B2))*(B2<>"")
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE

now possible with lambda:

```
=BYROW(B2:B6; LAMBDA(x; ISFORMULA(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this won't work for me. I'm trying to convert a `key value` table into JSON of `key cell_addres` but only for values that are not formulas. I'll have to figure something else out. Thanks!

Comment: How can you see which functions will return an array that you can use in `arrayformula`?

Comment: there is no official list so basically just a tail and error. ISFORMULA, SUM, OR, AND, AVERAGE, FORMULATEXT, STDV, GOOGLETRANSLATE, INDIRECT, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is so frustrating. I myself have made `areFormula()` by my needs. Not so elegant, but working. It [takes a range](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92156) of *row* or *column* (if *area*, treated as a *row*), and returns a row.

```
function areFormula(rowOrColumn) {
  // takes a range as input parameter
  // from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92156
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i)[1].split('!');
  try {
    if (args.length == 1) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(args[0]);
    }
    else {
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName(args[0].replace(/'/g, ''));
      range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args.join('!') + ' is not a valid range');
  }
  rowOrColumn = range;

  //here starts my code
  let values = rowOrColumn.getValues();

  let isItRow = true;
  if(values.length == 1) {
    isItRow = false;
    values = values[0];
  }
  else {
    values = values.map(el => el[0]);
  }

  let result = [];
  let x = 0, y = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const cell = rowOrColumn.getCell(1+y, 1+x);
    result.push(cell.getFormula() ? true : false);

    if(isItRow) 
      y++;
    else 
      x++;
  }

  console.log(result);
  return(result);  
}
```